# Ethernet Shield Issue

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet

I just bought a Ethernet Shield for my Arduino UNO. I connected it to my arduino and flashed the Example code for Ethernet Shield, but the code didn't work. The COLL LED on ethernet shield is glowing and I checked with my router, it has not assigned any IP to my ethernet shield. I tried all of the examples given, but none of them worked. Help me in understanding wrong I am doing here?

Ethernet Shield(W5100) Link: https://www.banggood.in/Ethernet-Shield-Module-W5100-Micro-SD-Card-Slot-For-Arduino-UNO-MEGA-p-908461.html?rmmds=search&cur_warehouse=CN

Exampled code given in Arduino (DhcpAddressPrinter):

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address for your controller below.
// Newer Ethernet shields have a MAC address printed on a sticker on the shield
byte mac[] = {
  0x00, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDE, 0x02
};

void setup() {
  // You can use Ethernet.init(pin) to configure the CS pin
  //Ethernet.init(10);  // Most Arduino shields
  //Ethernet.init(5);   // MKR ETH shield
  //Ethernet.init(0);   // Teensy 2.0
  //Ethernet.init(20);  // Teensy++ 2.0
  //Ethernet.init(15);  // ESP8266 with Adafruit Featherwing Ethernet
  //Ethernet.init(33);  // ESP32 with Adafruit Featherwing Ethernet

  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // start the Ethernet connection:
  Serial.println("Initialize Ethernet with DHCP:");
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetNoHardware) {
      Serial.println("Ethernet shield was not found.  Sorry, can't run without hardware. :(");
    } else if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF) {
      Serial.println("Ethernet cable is not connected.");
    }
    // no point in carrying on, so do nothing forevermore:
    while (true) {
      delay(1);
    }
  }
  // print your local IP address:
  Serial.print("My IP address: ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  switch (Ethernet.maintain()) {
    case 1:
      //renewed fail
      Serial.println("Error: renewed fail");
      break;

    case 2:
      //renewed success
      Serial.println("Renewed success");
      //print your local IP address:
      Serial.print("My IP address: ");
      Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
      break;

    case 3:
      //rebind fail
      Serial.println("Error: rebind fail");
      break;

    case 4:
      //rebind success
      Serial.println("Rebind success");
      //print your local IP address:
      Serial.print("My IP address: ");
      Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
      break;

    default:
      //nothing happened
      break;
  }
}
```

Output

```
Initialize Ethernet with DHCP:
```

Code I wrote for Webserver:

```
#include<SPI.h>
#include<Ethernet.h>

int led = 8;
byte mac[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xEF, 0xED};
EthernetServer server(80);
String readString;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  Ethernet.begin(mac);
  Serial.print("Server is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  EthernetClient client = server.available();

  if (client) {
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        Serial.print(c);

        if (readString.length() < 100) {
          readString += c;
        }

        if (c = '\n') {
          Serial.print(readString);
          client.println("<HTTP/1.1 200 0K>");
          client.print("<Connection-Type: text/html>");
          client.println("<Connection: close>");
          client.println("");

          client.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
          client.println("<html>");
          client.println("<head>");
          client.println("<title>Webserver</title>");
          client.println("</head>");
          client.println("<body>");
          client.println("<a href=\"/?button1on\"\"><button>LED ON</button></a>");
          client.println("<a href=\"/?button2off\"\"><button>LED OFF</button></a>");
          client.println("<body style=background-color:powderblue>");

          delay(1);
          client.stop();

          if (readString.indexOf("?button1on") > 0) {
            digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
          }

          if (readString.indexOf("?button2off") > 0) {
            digitalWrite(led, LOW);
          }
          readString = "";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output

```
Server is at 0.0.0.0
```

Thank You

Comment: Also what ethernet shield?

Comment: what do the examples print to Serial Monitor?

Comment: I have added the code in my question. The ethernet shield I am using is W5100

Comment: try this code  https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/Ethernet/examples/DhcpAddressPrinter/DhcpAddressPrinter.ino

Comment: Try disabling the SD. Add `pinMode(4, OUTPUT); digitalWrite(4, HIGH);` to the setup().

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for helping. I tried that code, but the serial monitor prints "Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP"

Comment: @MikaelPatel After adding those lines in setup(), the output in Serial monitor is same, "Server is at 0.0.0.0"

Comment: do you have the router set up with a whitelist of MAC addresses? .... also, you could try using a static IP

Comment: @darkpanda Did you put the code first in setup()?

Comment: @MikaelPatel yes